# How to delete all the files in a folder except read-only files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to delete all the files and subfolders from a folder except read-only files.

How to do it using powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only objects that can be read-only are files. When you use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet you are getting objects of type `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` back. The FileInfos have a property named `IsReadOnly`. So you can do this one liner:

`dir -recurse -path C:\Somewhere | ? {-not $_.IsReadOnly -and -not $_.PsIsContainer} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf`

The `PsIsContainer` property is created by PowerShell (Ps prefix gives it away) and tells whether or not the item is a file or folder. We can use this to pass only files to `Remove-Item`.

Remove `-WhatIf` when you are ready to delete for real.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, this is a bit easier in V3:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !r | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

or the short (alias) version:

```
dir -at !r | ri -r -f -wh
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the attribute of each folder and file and then do a conditional based deletion. This is just the pseudo code.

```
If (-not (a readonly file)) {
delete file
}
```

So, to check if a given file or folder is readonly:

```
$item = Get-Item C:\Scripts\Test.txt
$item.IsReadOnly
```

HTH